# How do you set up a Groovy ConditionalInterrupt from Java?

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to make a Groovy throw an InterruptedException using ConditionalInterrupt.  I am trying to build it from Java.  This is what I have done so far

```
final Binding binding = new Binding();
final CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
final Map<String, Object> annotationParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// this is my control variable, the code should only work if p is ""
final String p = "X"; 

// at this point I tried various things primarily to get the following closure
// { p.isEmpty() }
// intetionally removed because it looked really messy

annotationParameters.put("value", aStatementContainingClosure);

config.addCompilationCustomizers(new ASTTransformationCustomizer(
    annotationParameters, ConditionalInterrupt.class));

final GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding, config);
try {
    shell.evaluate("def a = 1;");
fail("Should not reach here");
} catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
assertTrue(e instanceof InterruptedException);
}
```

Just an FYI the following code block represents the last few tries I have done to get this working... (will remove this once we get a proper answer)

```
    binding.setVariable("p", p);

    final GroovyShell shell1 = new GroovyShell(binding);
    final Closure closure2 = (Closure) shell1
            .evaluate("{ it -> p.isEmpty() }");
    //final Closure closure2 = (Closure) shell1
    //      .evaluate("{ p -> p.isEmpty() }");
    final BlockStatement code = (BlockStatement) new AstBuilder()
            .buildFromString("def p = { System.out.println(1) }").get(0);
    final ClosureExpression cex = (ClosureExpression) ((ReturnStatement) code
            .getStatements().get(0)).getExpression();
    // final Expression expression = new BooleanExpression(
    // new MethodCallExpression(new VariableExpression("p"),
    // "isEmpty", new TupleExpression()));
    // final Expression expression = new MethodPointerExpression(
    // new VariableExpression("p"), new ConstantExpression("isEmpty"));
    // // final Statement code = new ExpressionStatement(expression);
    final ClosureExpression closure = new ClosureExpression(
            new Parameter[0], code);
    annotationParameters.put("value", cex);
```

Comment: Complete stab in the dark (not tried it), but could you do:  `Object aStatementContainingClosure = new GroovyShell().evaluate( "{ p -> p.isEmpty() }" ) ;`

Comment: Yup, tried it.  Didn't work well.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{ !p.isEmpty() }`?

Comment: I tried both, basically the result I have was it either fails on applying the AST Transformation or it will always hit the fail() block with my attempts.

Comment: Hmmm...this is the closest I can get https://gist.github.com/timyates/bffad7c32fcd6320bfdb but it says it can't find `p` :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but you should build closure yourself!

For example, my code, closure expression check static volatile field

```
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        map.put("value", new ClosureExpression(Parameter.EMPTY_ARRAY, 
                            GeneralUtils.returnS(GeneralUtils.eqX(
                                        GeneralUtils.fieldX(FieldNode.newStatic(ScriptService.class, "run")), 
                                        GeneralUtils.constX(false)) 
                                        )));
    } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    configuration.addCompilationCustomizers(
            new ASTTransformationCustomizer(map, ConditionalInterrupt.class));
```

Groovy is really powerful!